# Why is the API not working correctly?

Tags: javascript, html, json, api, access-token

Why is the submit button not outputting results as it should be? I can't seem to notice what could be wrong with the code. Basically it's an BMI API from Mashape (https://market.mashape.com/nviror/bmi-calculator) and I can't get it to work. I am new to JavaScript and API's so I can't solve this problem..
Here's the the javascript and the form part of the html:

```js
// TODO: Use a function closure and release global $
$.noConflict();
(function($){
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#bmi-form').on('submit', function(event) {
      //saving inputs
      var weight = $('#bmi-weight').val();
      var height = $('#bmi-height').val();
      
      $.get(
          'https://bmi.p.mashape.com/WyFUMDOkdrmshARoxfXDWLZmMeccp180tJEjsnCz3MCFuXJdEo' + weight + height,
          function(data,json){
            $('#bmi').append(
            '<p>Your BMI is: '+data.bmi.value+'</p>'
          );
          $('#bmi').append(
            '<p>Your status is: '+data.bmi.status+'</p>'
          );
          $('#bmi').append(
           '<p>Your risk is: '+data.bmi.risk+'</p>'
          );
      });  
        var string= 'Your Bmi: ' +value+ '. Your status:' +status+ '. Your risk:' +risk + '.';
        $('#results').text(string);

    });
  event.preventDefault();
  });
});(jQuery);
```

```html
<section id="bmi">
        <form id="bmi-form" name="bmi-form" method="get" action="#null">
          <label for="bmi-weight">Type in your weight:</label>
          <input type="text" id="bmi-weight" name="bmi-weight" />
          <label for="bmi-height">Type in your height:</label>
          <input type="text" id="bmi-height" type="text" name="bmi-height" />
          <input type="submit" id="bmi-submit" name="bmi-submit" value="Check BMI" />
        </form>
        <p id="results"></p>
      </section>
```

Comment: The API that you linked is using POST request, while you are using GET request. And also you need to construct the payload data as JSON

Comment: @OscarSiauw so are you saying that the API that I chose won't behave as I intended and that I should find an API that uses a GET request? Or am I doing something wrong...

Comment: The API is correct, but you need to use POST request instead. And construct your payload as JSON.

Example from the API documentation:
    {"weight":{"value":"85.00","unit":"kg"},"height":{"value":"170.00","unit":"cm"},"sex":"m","age":"24","waist":"34.00","hip":"40.00"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something like this:

Note: unfortunately I have not tested the code below

```
$.ajax(
    {
        method: "POST",
        url: "https://bmi.p.mashape.com/",
        headers: {
            "X-Mashape-Key": <enter your API key here>,
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Accept": "application/json"
        },
        data: '{"weight":{"value":"85.00","unit":"kg"},"height":{"value":"170.00","unit":"cm"},"sex":"m","age":"24","waist":"34.00","hip":"40.00"}'
    }
).done(function(){
    console.log("Done");
})
```

Comment: This does work but it automatically shows up on page load, I need it to show up when I press the submit button and with the values from the form instead of 85 & 170... But there's definitely some progress though...

Comment: Then call that on your button click event. And change the data payload with the values from the form.
I was just showing you an example on how to do POST request with JSON payload